# Django rest framework custom POST permissions

Tags: django, post, permissions, django-rest-framework

Using DRF to set up a plateform where users can share content, I'm having trouble checking if the author matches the logged user.

Example of a content model :

```
    class Post(models.Model):
        date = models.DateTimeField()
        author = models.ForeignKey(User)
        content = models.CharField(max_length=512)
```

Content serializer :

```
    class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = Post
```

Content view :

```
    @authentication_classes((SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication,))
    @permission_classes((IsAuthenticated,))
    class PostViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
        queryset = Post.objects.all()
        serializer_class = PostSerializer
        http_method_names = ['get', 'post', 'head', 'options',]
```

I want post requests to perform a post.author == request.user test before saving the post.

On one hand my intuition tells me I should overwrite the create method of the view, with that kind of code (not tested, but here I just want to give an idea of what I want to do) :

```
    class PostViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
        [...]
        def create(self, request):
            post = self.get_object()
            serializer = PostSerializer(data=request.data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                if serializer.validated_data.author == request.user:
                    serializer.save()
                    return Response({'message': 'Post saved !'})
                else:
                    return Response({'message': 'You can't post for someone else'})
            else:
                return Response({'message': 'Not valid...'})
```

On the other hand, when I search for similar problems on my favorite search engine I can only find answers which involve overwriting the create/update methods in the serializer class.

I'm not very familiar with rest apis nor with DRF, but I'm confused, because what I'm talking about is kind of a custom permission (permissions are handled in views, right ?).

Looking for good practices tips :)

Comment: Please change "post" to `POST` in your answer where you mean the HTTP method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Create

It does not make much sense to leave the `author` field editable to the user and then verify its value, you can just set it for the user in the  `create`. So in your serializer it would be:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        read_only_fields = ('author',)
```

Then in `PostViewSet`, **instead** of your `create`:

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    serializer.save(author=self.request.user)
```

`perform_create` is a hook which is called from `create` after the data validation, so you don't have to bother doing it and creating the `Response` yourself.

#### Update & delete

When you do updates or deletes though, you can add a custom permission class like `IsAuthorOrReadOnly` which verifies that `post.author == request.user`. You can inspire yourself from the [second example here (`IsOwnerOrReadOnly` class)](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#examples) which corresponds exactly to your needs.

You can then use it as any other permission class e.g.:

```
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated, IsAuthorOrReadOnly, ))
class PostViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    # ...
```